# Line integral on implicit region that can't easily be transformed to parametric region

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to integrate (numerical solution or precise solution) a function (e.g. `x^2 + y^2`), along a line (like `x^3 + y^4 + 2 x y == 1` from (1,0) to (0,1)) in the x-y plane. How can I do that? I know the `LineIntegrate` function, but it seems to integrate only a parametric form.

Comment: Do you need a numeric solution or symbolic solution?

Comment: All OK. I just want to konw how to Integrate this in Mathematica

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If numeric solution is OK, then it's easy at least for the specific problem in the question:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[x^3 + y^4 + 2 x y == 1, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}];

NIntegrate[x^2 + y^2, {x, y} ∈ reg]
(* 1.12535 *)
```

Comment: This was very useful and exactly the answer I was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

We may get dy/dx from the implicit equation and then solve the differential equation for y[x]. With this we can do the line integral. dy/dy from the implicit equation is:

```
y'[x]== -(3 x^2 + 2 y[x])/(4 y[x]^3 + 2 x)
```

With the initial condition of y[0]:

```
y[0] == 1
```

we can solve the DE:

```
f[x_] / y /. NDSolve[{y'[x]== -(3 x^2 + 2 y[x])/(4 y[x]^3 + 2 x),y[0]==1},y,{x,0,1}]
```

Having now the function y== f[x] we can calculate the line integral:

```
NIntegrate[(x^2 + f[x]^2 ) Sqrt[1 + f'[x]^2], {x, 0, 1}]

1.12535
```

Comment: Or just `NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == -(3 x^2 + 2 y[x])/(4 y[x]^3 + 2 x), y[0] == 1, u'[x] == (x^2 + y[x]^2) Sqrt[1 + y'[x]^2], u[0] == 0}, u[1], {x, 0, 1}]`

Answer (score 8):

A parametrization is possible:

```
y0 = Normal@
   First@SolveValues[x^3 + y^4 + 2 x y == 1 && y > 0 && 0 < x < 1, y, 
     Reals];
preg = ParametricRegion[{x, y0}, {{x, 0, 1}}];
LineIntegrate[x^2 + y^2, {x, y} \[Element] N@preg]
(*  1.12535  *)
```

(I used `N@preg` to invoke `NIntegrate` under the hood, since the exact integral takes too long for me.  Omit the `N@` and see if you have enough patience.)